# How can i duplicate records with T-SQL and keep track of the progressive number?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, loops, t-sql

How can I duplicate the records of table1 and store them in table2 along with the progressive number calculated from startnum and endnum?
Thanks

the first row must be duplicated in 4 records i.e num: 80,81,82,83

```
Startnum |      Endnum |    Data
---------+-------------+----------
      80 |          83 |    A
      10 |          11 |    C
      14 |          16 |    D
```

Result:

```
StartEndNum |   Data
------------+-----------
         80 |   A
         81 |   A
         82 |   A
         83 |   A
         10 |   C
         11 |   C
         14 |   D
         15 |   D
         16 |   D
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without recursion:

```
declare @t table(Startnum int, Endnum int, Data varchar(20))
insert into @t values
(80, 83, 'A'),
(10, 11, 'C'),
(14, 16, 'D');


select a.StartEndNum, t.Data
from @t t cross apply (select top (t.Endnum - t.Startnum + 1) 
                                   t.Startnum + row_number() over(order by getdate()) - 1 as StartEndNum
                     from sys.all_columns) a;
```

You can use any other table with enough rows instead of `sys.all_columns`

Answer (score 2):

A simple method uses a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as 
      select startnum, endnum, data
      from t
      union all
      select startnum + 1, endnum, data
      from cte
      where startnum < endnum
     )
select startnum, data
from cte;
```

If you have ranges that exceed 100, you need `option (maxrecursion 0)`.

Note:  There are other solutions as well, using numbers tables (either built-in or generated).  I like this solution as a gentle introduction to recursive CTEs.